# firebase storage not running unless code changed with hot reload in vuejs2

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-storage

I'm creating an image loading app. The image details are stored in firestore and are retrieved successfully. The image name is then used to create the path for Firebase storage. However the function `Firebase.storage.ref(...path).getDownloadURL()` does not run at all, including the callback `.then(...)` or `.catch(...)`. Unless the code is changed in the created method while 'npm run serve' is running.
Thanks in advance.

Using Firebase version 5.11.0 on npm 6.4.1 and node v10.15.3 on a machine running Ubuntu 19. Vue-cli version 3.7.0. Also uses eslint

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
  name:'imageView',
  props: ["imaGes"],
  data(){
    return{
      imageURLs:[]
    }
  },
  created(){
    console.log('start')
    var storage = firebase.storage();
    this.imaGes.forEach(iMaGe => {
      //console.log(iMaGe.image_name)
    var storageRef = storage.ref('images_img/'+iMaGe.image_name);
    console.log('reference completee')
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url =>{
      //console.log('bo')
      const data = url;
      this.imageURLs.push(data);
      //console.log('get completed')
      //console.log('hi')
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
    });
    console.log('completed')
  }
}
```

The array imageURLs should be populated with download urls from Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to execute in parallel the calls to the asynchronous `getDownloadURL()` method.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
  name:'imageView',
  props: ["imaGes"],
  data(){
    return{
      imageURLs:[]
    }
  },
  created(){
    console.log('start')
    var storage = firebase.storage();

    const promises = [];

    this.imaGes.forEach(iMaGe => {
      var storageRef = storage.ref('images_img/'+iMaGe.image_name);
      console.log('reference completee')
      promises.push(storageRef.getDownloadURL());
    });

    return Promise.all(promises)   
    .then(results => {
        this.imageURLs = results;
    })
    .catch(err=>{
       console.log(err)
    });
  }
}
```

Note also a typo in `iMage.image_name`.

Comment: Thanks for helping but i tried it out and the issue still exists,the function Promise.all() does resolve however returns a null set when initial complied. However when the site is being hot reloaded and any change is made then a populated array is rreturned

Comment: there is no error or output in the console except for the console.log() statements

Comment: Are you sure the props are correctly passed and that you have a correct value of `this.imaGes`? What do you get if you do `console.log(this.imaGes);` before the `forEach`?

Comment: yes, as i said before everything works perfectly with parsing and sending, even if i just change a character within the function while the page is already being run on a development server the URL are received